# Show that $X \setminus A$ is locally compact.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, compactification

> Let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space and $A \subseteq X$ be a closed set. Then $X \setminus A$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space.

That $X \setminus A$ is Hausdorff is quite clear as it is a subspace of a Hausdorff space $X.$ How do I prove that $X \setminus A$ is locally compact? Let $x \in X \setminus A.$ How do I get hold of a compact subset $C_x$ of $X \setminus A$ containing a neighbourhood of $x\ $? Does openness of $X \setminus A$ have something to do with local compactness? I need some help at this stage.

Also I have another question. We know that every locally compact Hausdorff space has a one point compactification. So if $X \setminus A$ is proved to be locally compact what will be it's one point compactification? Any help or suggestion in this regard will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If we can find out an open neighbourhood $U_x$ of $x$ in $X \setminus A$ whose closure in $X$ is contained in $X \setminus A$ then we are through because then $\overline {U_x}$ is compact as it is a closed subset of the compact set $X.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $x\in X\setminus A$. Since $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, it is a normal space. So, since $A$ and $\{x\}$ are closed sets, there are open sets $B$ and $C$ such that $A\subset B$, $x\in C$ and $B\cap C=\emptyset$. But then $C$ is a neighborhood of $x$ and therefore $B^\complement$ is also a neighborhood of $x$. But $B^\complement$ is compact, since it is closed.

Comment: Can you share some idea on how to determine it's one point compactification?

Comment: If $Y$ is any locally compact Hausdorff space, a one point compactification of $Y$ is $Y\cup\{\infty\}$, where, if $C\subset Y\cup\{x\}$ $C$ is an open set if $C$ is an open subset of $Y$ or (when $\infty\in C$) if $C^\complement$ is a compact subset of $Y$.

Comment: Can you please be more explicit? Do you want me to post it as a separate question?

Comment: *How* can I be more explicit?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly the one point compactification of $X \setminus A$ is.

Comment: It's $(X\setminus A)\cup\{\infty\}$ with the following topology: if $S\subset(X\setminus A)\cup\{\infty\}$ then we say that $S$ is an open set if it is an open subset of $X\setminus A$ (in which case $S\subset X\setminus A$ and therefore $\infty\notin S$) or if $\infty\in S$ and $\bigl((X\setminus A)\cup\{\infty\}\bigr)\setminus S(\subset X\setminus A)$ is a compact subset of $X\setminus A$.

Comment: Our instructor proposed that one point compactification of $X \setminus A$ is nothing but $X / A.$ How do I prove that? That means we need to get a homeomorphism between these two spaces.

Comment: The same way I did: consider the topology in $X/A$ which consists of two types of sets: the open subsets of $X\setminus A$ and the subsets $S$ of $X/A$ such that $A\subset S$ and that $S^\complement$ is a compact subset of $X\setminus A$.